# Appium - find element by Xpath

Tags: java, android, appium

I have one issue which I can't resolve...
I'm trying to write automated tests with Appium...
We don't have unique elements in our application except Text. 
As example we have some element which i want to click. This element has not uniquely id "elements" (many of others elements on this page have the same id) but this element has as unique text "Track"... 
As I know one chance for me it's find this element by Xpath but unfortunately I can't do this and when I run my tests i get one by one exceptions...(

My xpath is:

```
//*[@id='elements' and contains(text(),'Track']
```

What I should change in my xpath? how to build it correctly?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a few mistakes in your XPath, This should work:

```
//*[@resource-id='elements' and contains(@text,'Track')]
```

before you go any further with your automation project, visit this site:

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html

Comment: I have issue with finding element on Mac Mojave VM only. The appium based applications works well on my local windows environment. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='elements' and contains(text(),'Track')]")).clear();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer.